# Jupyterlab Inline Interactive plot

Tags: visualization, matplotlib, jupyter, ipython

I am trying to make my inline plots in jupyterlab interactive. So far, I have tried a suggestion as pointed out here, among others:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149562/jupyterlab-interactive-plot

```
# %matplotlib notebook - does not work : Javascript Error: IPython is not defined
# %matplotlib widget - works, but plots are overwritten
```

The widget magic works in making the plots interactive, but unfortunately, my plots are overwritten. Subsequent cells render plots on top of the output of cell 1 as below:

```
plt.scatter(trainData['x'], trainData['y'], color='Red', s=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
plt.hist(trainData['x'])
plt.xlabel("Values of X")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
plt.hist(trainData['y'])
plt.xlabel("Values of Y")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
```

[image]

This does not look right, have I missed an option? I am looking for an IPython magic that can help with having several inline plots (after each cell)?

I am using jupyterlab v 0.35.4, run from Anaconda navigator.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to create a new figure before plotting by `plt.figure()`, or you need to use subplots. Otherwise, `plt.show()` will act on the last-created figure.
[image]